# Weird java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, primefaces

I have a weird problem with my application. I am using Spring-webflow with Primefaces and i would like to switch to sprind-data-jpa.

Here is my backingBean.

```
@Component
@Scope("flow")
public class CustomerUI implements Serializable {

@Autowired
private ICustomerService customerService;

private List<Customer> customerList;

private LazyDataModel<Customer> customerLazyDataModel;


public void init() {
    customerLazyDataModel = new LazyDataModel<Customer>() {
        @Override
        public List<Customer> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
            return customerService.listCustomers(first,pageSize);
        }
    };
}

public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
    return customerList;
}

public void setCustomerList(List<Customer> customerList) {
    this.customerList = customerList;
}

public LazyDataModel<Customer> getCustomerLazyDataModel() {
    return customerLazyDataModel;
}

public void setCustomerLazyDataModel(LazyDataModel<Customer> customerLazyDataModel) {
    this.customerLazyDataModel = customerLazyDataModel;
}
}
```

Here is my Service, it is now partially mocked:

```
 @Service
 public class CustomerImplementation implements ICustomerService {

@Autowired
private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

@Override
public int getPagesCount(int perPage) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Customer persist(Customer customer) {
    if(customer.getNewAddress() != null && !customer.getNewAddress().equals(""))
    {
        if(customer.getAddress() != null && customer.getAddress().size() > 0)
        {
            boolean found = false;
            for(Address address : customer.getAddress())
            {
                      if(address.getAddress().equals(customer.getNewAddress()))
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!found)
            {
                Address address = new Address();
                address.setAddress(customer.getNewAddress());
                address.setCustomer(customer);
                customer.getAddress().add(address);
            }
        }else{
            Address address = new Address();
            address.setAddress(customer.getNewAddress());
            address.setCustomer(customer);
            if(customer.getAddress() == null)
            {
                customer.setAddress(new LinkedList<Address>());
            }
            customer.getAddress().add(address);
        }
    }
    return customerRepository.save(customer);
}

@Override
public List<Customer> listCustomers(int page, int limit) {
    List<Customer> customers;

    customers = customerRepository.findAll();
    return customers;
}

@Override
public List<Customer> findCustomersByString(String search) {
    search = search.toLowerCase();
    return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
}

@Override
public Customer findCustomerById(int id) {
    return customerRepository.findOne(id);
}

@Override
public Customer persistRepo(Customer customer) {
    return customerRepository.save(customer);
}
}
```

And here goes the Stack:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotCreationException: Could not serialize flow execution; make sure all objects stored in flow or flash scope are serializable

 type Exception report

  message Request processing failed; nested exception is  org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotCreation Exception: Could not serialize flow execution; make sure all objects  stored in flow or flash scope are serializable

 description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

 exception

 org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotCreationException: Could not serialize flow execution; make sure all objects stored in flow or flash scope are serializable
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 root cause

    org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotCreationException: Could not serialize flow execution; make sure all objects stored in flow or flash scope are serializable
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.<init>(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.java:75)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshotFactory.createSnapshot(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshotFactory.java:70)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.AbstractSnapshottingFlowExecutionRepository.snapshot(AbstractSnapshottingFlowExecutionRepository.java:75)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.putFlowExecution(DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.java:126)
org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:145)
org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:238)
org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:57)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

 root cause

 java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor
- field (class "org.springframework.aop.support.AbstractGenericPointcutAdvisor", name: "advice", type: "interface org.aopalliance.aop.Advice")
- object (class "org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor", org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor@711b8820])
- element of array (index: 2)
- array (class "[Lorg.springframework.aop.Advisor;", size: 7)
- field (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport", name: "advisorArray", type: "class [Lorg.springframework.aop.Advisor;")
- object (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory", org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory: 3 interfaces [pl.modern.backend.api.CustomerRepository, org.springframework.data.repository.Repository, org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionalProxy]; 7 advisors [org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor@431137d2], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [INSTANCE], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor@711b8820], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor@2044544f], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor@3b3db6f], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor@49d6d36c], org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor@4f1a3176]; targetSource [SingletonTargetSource for target object [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository@66303788]]; proxyTargetClass=false; optimize=false; opaque=false; exposeProxy=false; frozen=false)
- field (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy", name: "advised", type: "class org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport")
- object (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy", org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy@caadae9a)
- field (class "java.lang.reflect.Proxy", name: "h", type: "interface java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler")
- object (class "com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65", org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository@66303788)
- field (class "pl.modern.services.CustomerImplementation", name: "customerRepository", type: "interface pl.modern.backend.api.CustomerRepository")
- object (class "pl.modern.services.CustomerImplementation", pl.modern.services.CustomerImplementation@7bd072c1)
- field (class "pl.modern.modernsoft.ui.customer.CustomerUI", name: "customerService", type: "interface pl.modern.services.ICustomerService")
- object (class "pl.modern.modernsoft.ui.customer.CustomerUI", pl.modern.modernsoft.ui.customer.CustomerUI@7c1ebb03)
- custom writeObject data (class "java.util.HashMap")
- object (class "java.util.HashMap", {viewScope=map[[empty]], customerUI=pl.modern.modernsoft.ui.customer.CustomerUI@7c1ebb03, persistenceContext=org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@2b3f5ee5})
- field (class "org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.LocalAttributeMap", name: "attributes", type: "interface java.util.Map")
- custom writeObject data (class "org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.LocalAttributeMap")
- object (class "org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.LocalAttributeMap", map['viewScope' -> map[[empty]], 'customerUI' -> pl.modern.modernsoft.ui.customer.CustomerUI@7c1ebb03, 'persistenceContext' -> org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@2b3f5ee5])
- writeExternal data
- object (class "org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowSessionImpl", [FlowSessionImpl@506613bb flow = 'customer', state = 'list', scope = map['viewScope' -> map[[empty]], 'customerUI' -> pl.modern.modernsoft.ui.customer.CustomerUI@7c1ebb03, 'persistenceContext' -> org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@2b3f5ee5]])
- custom writeObject data (class "java.util.LinkedList")
- object (class "java.util.LinkedList", [[FlowSessionImpl@506613bb flow = 'customer', state = 'list', scope = map['viewScope' -> map[[empty]], 'customerUI' -> pl.modern.modernsoft.ui.customer.CustomerUI@7c1ebb03, 'persistenceContext' -> org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@2b3f5ee5]]])
- writeExternal data
- root object (class "org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl", [FlowExecutionImpl@7e21c721 flow = 'customer', flowSessions = list[[FlowSessionImpl@506613bb flow = 'customer', state = 'list', scope = map['viewScope' -> map[[empty]], 'customerUI' -> pl.modern.modernsoft.ui.customer.CustomerUI@7c1ebb03, 'persistenceContext' -> org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@2b3f5ee5]]]])
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1182)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1777)
java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1354)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor77.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:441)
org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.LocalAttributeMap.writeObject(LocalAttributeMap.java:333)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowSessionImpl.writeExternal(FlowSessionImpl.java:162)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1459)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1430)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
java.util.LinkedList.writeObject(LinkedList.java:1131)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.writeExternal(FlowExecutionImpl.java:311)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1459)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1430)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.serialize(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.java:173)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.<init>(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.java:70)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshotFactory.createSnapshot(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshotFactory.java:70)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.AbstractSnapshottingFlowExecutionRepository.snapshot(AbstractSnapshottingFlowExecutionRepository.java:75)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.putFlowExecution(DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.java:126)
org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:145)
org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:238)
org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:57)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
```

Comment: Did you read the first lines of the error? And did you check what it states?

Comment: Yes I did. So I have changed my Services to implement Serializable, but that didnt help, because one of the not managed by me depenedncy is not serializable.

Comment: Then you don't have a weird problem, but a normal problem that can only be solved by making it transient or whatever. Plain simple basic problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I had to add `<flow-execution-repository max-execution-snapshots="0"/>` in `flow-executor` defintion.